# inject interface dependency in singleton class using unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using `Unity` for `dependency injection` so far its working fine except using dependency in singleton class.

I have one static class to access database functions

```
public class DB
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<DB> lazy = new Lazy<DB>(() => new DB());
        public static DB Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

        private readonly IContactService _contactService;

        private DB() { }
        public DB(IContactService contactService)
        {

            _contactService = contactService;
        }
}
```

Now, the issue is `IContactService` is dependent on `ContactService` class as  `DB` uses `_contactService` in order to make web service call. Even after registering DB as singleton using `Unity`, i am getting `_contactService` as `null`.

registering DB class

```
     _container = new UnityContainer();
     _container.RegisterSingleton<DB>();
```

Comment: Have you also registered `IContactService`?

Comment: Did you register `ContactService`? Please show us the constructor for `IContactService`.

Comment: Yes it is register as  ` _container.RegisterType<IContactService, ContactService>();` as other classes are also using the same

Comment: How are you getting your instance of `DB`? If you are using the `Instance` property, then that's not going to work.

Comment: Yes I am using `DB.Instance.methodName`

Comment: Then you are not using DI for your `DB` class. Instead inject it like you are doing for the `IContactService` and remove the static members from the class.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as m not able to get it :(

Comment: In your class where you use the `DB` object, pass a DB in the constructor. Just normal DI.

Comment: What do you think `new DB()` does? Which constructor do you think it calls?

Comment: When I use `DB.Instance` it's not calling any constructor

Comment: It is calling the `private DB() { }` constructor (the first time anyway).

Comment: But what is the solution

Comment: Remove `private static readonly Lazy<DB> lazy = new Lazy<DB>(() => new DB());
        public static DB Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }` and DI in `DB` when you need it.

Comment: then how would i call methods in DB from other class , sorry m new to DI

Comment: shall i use `Locator.Instance.Resolve<DB>()`  every time i need to call DB's method ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your DB class to something like:

```
public class DB {
  private readonly IContactService _contactService;

  public DB(IContactService contactService) {
    _contactService = contactService;
  }
  ...
}
```

Wherever you were using `DB.Instance`, inject DB as a dependency and use that. Or use `Locator.Instance.Resolve<DB>()` although using a ServiceLocator is considered an anti pattern (depends).

Since you are registering DB as singleton in your DI container, it is the responsibility of the container to always return the same instance wherever it is injected. You don't need to write code in DB to make it a singleton.